# Managing JIRA webhooks via REST API

Tags: java, rest, jira, webhooks

I'm trying to manage JIRA via java REST API. following are my questions:
1. How do I pass arguments in URL via webhook while calling my REST code.
2. How do I receive the request passed via webhook in my REST code.

I created a webhook and called my rest api in the url provided http://localhost:8080/rest/JIRAIntegration/JIRAService/record

While my rest code looks like

```
    @Path("/JiraService")
    public class JiraService {

    @GET
    @Path("/records")
    public String getJiraRequest(InputStream response){
     //req.getParameter("key");
  BufferedReader br = null;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
  try {
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
     }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("Inputstream::"+sb.toString());
  return sb.toString();
```

}

I'm new to JIRA webhooks as well as REST. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To receivie response from Webhook. You need to create a webhook in jira and give 
a url that can be access publicly. 
your code should be running on port 80 or 443.

Now say for example your link to rest is 
POST Call : http://xyz.abc.com/webservice/rest/jira/

In webhook you should give url as http://xyz.abc.com/webservice/rest/jira/

Your rest controller will have follwing rest method

> @POST()
>       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
>       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
>       public Response postMsg(String h) {
>
> ```
>     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
>     JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
>     JsonElement je = jp.parse(h);
>     String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
>     System.out.println("################################");
>     System.out.println(prettyJsonString);
>     String output = prettyJsonString;
>
>     return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
>
> }
> ```

Now after doing this you should configure webhook  to send respone on Jira ticket created or updated etc.